# TFS2018 TFVC On-Premise Build Definition How to include a solution in other Team Projects

Tags: tfvc, build-definition

Our solution (A) references a shared project located in another Team Project (B) under the same collection in Source Control (Not Git).

Creating my build definition for Solution (A), under "Get sources" "Workspace mappings" I'm adding the following:

**Type**

**Serverpath**

**Local path under $(build.sourcesDirectory)**

Map

$/TeamProjectB/ProjectB/Main/Source/ProjectB_Solution

$(build.sourcesDirectory)\ProjectB\

Map

$/TeamProjectA/ProjectA/Main/Source/ProjectA_Solution

$(build.sourcesDirectory)

But when I build I get:

> D:\Auto_build\31\s\$(build.sourcesDirectory)\ ..\ ..\ ..\ ..\ ..\TeamProjectB\ProjectB\Main\Source\ProjectB_Solution\Source\ProjectB\ProjectB.vbproj" was not found.

So I (think) I have both solutions within $(build.sourcesDirectory), but what am I doing wrong with the mappings for it not to find ProjectB.vbproj? Or is there a different reason? Help on this will be immensely appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Validate that the files are where you're expecting them to be relative to the references you have. If the files are there, then your references are pointing to the wrong location and you'll need to adjust your mappings accordingly. Or you can investigate doing the right thing and keep all common source code under the same team project *or* use NuGet packages.

Comment: Can you go the agent sources folder and check exactly what downloaded and where?